# Data is not entered in the table of my database

Tags: php, mysql, database, blob

I have to enter the audi in a column of a particular for a given user (in long blob).
The code is this

```
$audi = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['audi']['tmp_name']));
$audi_na = addslashes($_FILES['audi']['name']);


$tab=$_SESSION['email'];


   mysql_query("UPDATE  `database`.`TableOfUsers` SET  `audio` = '$audi'      AND `audiname` = '$audi_name' WHERE   WHERE  `user`.`email` = '$tab'") or die(mysql_error());
```

but my data is not being stored in the table..... something else get stored in the table with size 1 byte (always) but not required data.

I am beginner so pardon me if I am asking a silly question.

Comment: this is because you are using "where" clause twice.

Comment: You have added WHERE 2times and for multiple column update you can separate them with comma....See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of wrong in your query...correct them

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `database`.`TableOfUsers` 
             SET  `audio` = '$audi', `audiname` = '$audi_name' 
             WHERE  `user`.`email` = '$tab'") or die(mysql_error());
```

You have added WHERE 2times and for multiple column update you can separate them with comma

Answer (score 0):

In your query there is a syntax error. There is `WHERE` repeated two times. And also when you have multiple column updates you have to separate  with them with `,` not with `AND` i hope it will work.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `database`.`TableOfUsers` 
SET  `audio` = '$audi',  
`audiname` = '$audi_name' 
WHERE  `user`.`email` = '$tab'
")  or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: No.....For multiple column update you need to seperate with comma between them not with AND.....You have seperated them with AND which will not work

Answer (score 0):

You are using `where` 2 times in query. Make your query like this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `database`.`TableOfUsers` SET  `audio` = '$audi'      AND `audiname` = '$audi_name' WHERE  `user`.`email` = '$tab'") or die(mysql_error());
```

If you have `mysql_error()`, you should know the error

Comment: I've voted up, for mysql_error(), it displays the error of the above mentioned query

Comment: @NaJa then there is some thing else wrong with your script. Check if `error reporting` is allowed